# How I can get the serial number of the primary hard disk using php

Tags: php, windows

I was using:

```
$serial =  shell_exec('wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber 2>&1');
```

But with this I get all the hard disk serial number, I just want the serial number of the primary hard disk, in my case "c". 
I tried with this:

```
wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0" get serialnumber
```

It works fine in the windows console, but I tried to use it with `exec` like this:

```
$serial =  exec('wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid="\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0" get serialnumber');
```

But I just get ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) returns only the last line of output. Either give it its output argument, which it'll fill in with each line, or use [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead. Also double up on your [backslashes](https://xkcd.com/1638/) so they're escaped properly. E.g.:

```
exec('wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid="\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDRIVE0" get serialnumber', $out);
var_dump($out);
```

or

```
$serial = shell_exec('wmic path win32_diskdrive where deviceid="\\\\\\\\.\\\\PHYSICALDRIVE0" get serialnumber');
```